# Рекурсия. Таймер обратного отсчета. Как работает этот код в цикле "после", почему i начинает снова увеличиваться?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу понять, почему этот код (строка 8), там где "После" снова начинает выдавать 2, 3, 4, 5? За счет чего i снова начинает расти?

Код:

```py
def countdown(i):
    print(i)
    
    if i <= 1:
        return
    else:
        print("До i =", i)
        countdown(i - 1)
        print("После i =", i)
countdown(5)
```

Вывод:

```
4  
До i = 4  
3  
До i = 3  
2  
До i = 2  
1  
После i = 2  
После i = 3   
После i = 4   
После i = 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что вы возвращаетесь из рекурсии. И каждая функция хранит своё значение 'i' (вы же его не меняете, а только передаёте уменьшенное значение следующей функции).
Аналогия - это как бы у вас есть 5 одинаковых функций `a()`, `b()`, `c()`, `d()`, `e()` и вы зовёте их друг из друга:

```
def a(i):
    print("До i =", i)
    b(i - 1)
    print("После i =", i)

def b(i):
    print("До i =", i)
    c(i - 1)
    print("После i =", i)

def c(i):
    print("До i =", i)
    d(i - 1)
    print("После i =", i)

def d(i):
    print("До i =", i)
    e(i - 1)
    print("После i =", i)

def e(i):
    print(i)

a(5)
```

Выведет:

```
До i = 5
До i = 4
До i = 3
До i = 2
1
После i = 2
После i = 3
После i = 4
После i = 5
```

Comment: Спасибо! Стало гораздо понятнее.